# Can't the gcc linker just find my other files?

Tags: c, gcc, import, compilation, linker

So here's something I don't understand : Every single time you include something in c, you have to do `#include "dir/subdir/file.h"`. Since the `.c` file is in the **exact** same place, why do I also have to do `gcc main.c dir/subdir/file.c -o main` ?

It doesn't seem to make sense, every single other language I've used (arguably not that many, but still, several) was able to make sense of imports on its own. Am I missing something ? Is there a way to tell gcc to "just find them yourself" ?

Comment: You should probably look at build systems such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: The C compilers does not assume any particular project layout (there are plenty of projects that don’t follow your “`.c` file is in the exact same place” layout), so the functionality you’re looking for is delegated to build systems e.g. Make, CMake, Meson etc. Also note that `#include` in C and C++ merely dumps the included files textually into the code, which is far from being a proper import mechanism as seen in other languages like Python (C++ is gaining module support starting from C++20, but not C).

Comment: IIRC, some compilers, like Sun Studio (now dead), were indeed able to automatically compile the source file corresponding to an included header file. However, a much more common way to make things automatic is to use `gcc -MD` or similar to extract dependencies and let `make` see this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is a product of early 1970s, and this is one of the areas where that really shows.  An `#include` statement simply loads the contents of the specified file before it gets compiled - the path of the included file isn't being analyzed or preserved anywhere.  Similarly, `gcc` isn't preserving the path of any of the files on the command line - it just loads the source from the specified file, translates it, and spits out an object file at the end.

C doesn't specify any kind of package management semantics.  Each file on the `gcc` command line is compiled separately, and `gcc` doesn't know anything about the environment other than what's specified on the command line.

Yes, you *could* build a compiler that does all that analysis and tries to be smart about paths and such, but it's a crapload of work, there's no specification for it, no two compilers would do it the same way, and it kind of violates the spirit of C (the programmer is assumed to always know what they're doing, even when they don't).

---

Having said all that...

With `gcc`, you can use the `-I` option to specify additional include paths:

```
gcc -o main -I /dir/subdir main.c /dir/subdir/file.c
```

so in your source you don't need to use an explicit path in the `#include`:

```
#include "file.h"  // no need for /dir/subdir path
```

Similarly, you can use `-L` to specify additional directories to search for libraries (linked with `-l`):

```
gcc -o main -I /dir/subdir main.c /dir/subdir/file.c -L /anotherdir/subdir/libs -lmylib.a
```

Like Eric says, if you're having to manage source across multiple directories, you should be using `make` or a similar tool - doing all this manually on the command line rapidly gets unscalable.

**EDIT**

I think an example may be helpful.  I have a simple C program made up of three files - `main.c`, `foo.c`, and `bar.c`:

```
/**
 * main.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Notice no explicit path on either include
 */
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main( void )
{
  printf( "calling foo: " );
  foo();
  printf( "calling bar: " );
  bar();

  return 0;
}

/**
 * foo.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void foo( void )
{
  puts( "In function foo" );
}

/**
 * bar.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h"

void bar( void )
{
  puts( "In function bar" );
}
```

Because I'm insane, I've split the source code up over multiple directories like so:

```
make_example/
  Makefile
  build/
  include/
  package/
  src/
    main.c
    subdir.mk
    Makefile
    subdir1/
      Makefile
      foo.c
      foo.h
    subdir2/
      Makefile
      bar.c
      bar.h
```

I want to do the following:

- Build `foo.c` and `bar.c` and write their object files to `make_example/build`;
- Copy `foo.h` and `bar.h` to `make_example/include`;
- Build `main.c`, which includes the headers for `foo` and `bar` from `make_example/includes`, and write its object file to `make_example/build`;
- Build an executable named `demo` from `main.o`, `foo.o`, and `bar.o` and save it to the `make_example/package` directory.

IOW, after my build is done, I want the following:

```
make_example/
  Makefile
  build/
    bar.o
    foo.o
    main.o
  include/
    bar.h
    foo.h
  package/
    demo
  src/
    main.c
    subdir.mk
    Makefile
    subdir1/
      Makefile
      foo.c
      foo.h
    subdir2/
      Makefile
      bar.c
      bar.h
```

I have a `Makefile` at the top level directory and each of my source directories.  Here's the top-level Makefile (`make_example/Makefile`):

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror

TARGET=package/demo
SUBDIRS=src

all: $(TARGET)

# 
# Makes sure we build all source subdirectories before
# attempting to build the target
#
$(TARGET) : $(SUBDIRS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(wildcard build/*.o)

#
# Executes the Makefile in each source subdirectory
# with the current goal (all or clean)
#
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

clean: $(SUBDIRS)
    rm -rf $(TARGET)

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS) all clean
```

Here's the `Makefile` for the top-level source directory (`make_example/src/Makefile`):

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g 

TOPDIR=..
BLDDIR=$(TOPDIR)/build
INCDIR=$(TOPDIR)/include

#
# Look for foo.h and bar.h in the ../include
# subdirectory.  
#
CFLAGS += -I $(INCDIR)

SUBDIRS=$(wildcard subdir*/.)

SRCS=main.c
OBJS=$(SRCS:%.c=$(BLDDIR)/%.o)

TARGET=main

#
# Required for the $(OBJS) target - expands
# all of the $$ expressions
#
.SECONDEXPANSION:

all: $(TARGET)

#
# Makes sure the subdirectories are
# built before attempting to build our
# target
#
$(TARGET) : $(SUBDIRS) $(OBJS)

#
# Executes the Makefile in each of the source
# subdirectories with the current goal (all or clean)
#
$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

$(OBJS): $$(patsubst $(BLDDIR)/%.o, %.c, $$@)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

clean: $(SUBDIRS) 
    rm -rf $(OBJS)

.PHONY: all $(TARGET) $(SUBDIRS)
```

Since the `Makefile` for each of `subdir1` and `subdir2` is identical except for the file names, I created the `subdir.mk` file for the stuff that's common between the two:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g

TOPDIR=../..
BLDDIR=$(TOPDIR)/build
INCDIR=$(TOPDIR)/include

OBJS=$(SRCS:%.c=$(BLDDIR)/%.o)
HDRS=$(SRCS:%.c=$(INCDIR)/%.h)

all: $(OBJS) $(HDRS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) $(HDRS)

#
# Required for the $(OBJS) and $(HDRS) targets - expands
# all of the $$ expressions
#
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(OBJS) : $$(patsubst $(BLDDIR)/%.o,%.c,$$@)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

#
# Copy the header files to the ../../include
# directory
#
$(HDRS) : $$(patsubst $(INCDIR)/%.h,%.h,$$@)
    cp $< $@

.PHONY: all clean
```

Then each of the `make_example/src/subdir*` Makefiles is

```
SRCS=foo.c
include ../subdir.mk
```

and

```
SRCS=bar.c
include ../subdir.mk
```

So, at the top level (`make_example`), we simply type

```
make
```

which gives us

```
$ make
make -C src 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src'
make -C subdir2/. 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir2'
gcc -c -o ../../build/bar.o -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g bar.c
cp bar.h ../../include/bar.h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir2'
make -C subdir1/. 
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir1'
gcc -c -o ../../build/foo.o -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g foo.c
cp foo.h ../../include/foo.h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir1'
gcc -c -o ../build/main.o -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g  -I ../include main.c
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src'
gcc -o package/demo -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror build/foo.o build/main.o build/bar.o
```

And now we have all our build artifacts where we want them:

```
$ ls -l */*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  5744 Oct 23 16:13 build/bar.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  5744 Oct 23 16:13 build/foo.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  5984 Oct 23 16:13 build/main.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john    56 Oct 23 16:13 include/bar.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john    56 Oct 23 16:13 include/foo.h
-rwxrwxr-x 1 john john 21752 Oct 23 16:13 package/demo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john   165 Oct 23 12:54 src/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john   555 Oct 23 15:50 src/Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john   481 Oct 23 15:46 src/subdir.mk

src/subdir1:
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 89 Oct 23 12:29 foo.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 56 Oct 23 12:07 foo.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 32 Oct 23 15:16 Makefile

src/subdir2:
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 89 Oct 23 15:03 bar.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 56 Oct 23 14:49 bar.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 32 Oct 23 15:17 Makefile
```

And our program runs as

```
$ ./package/demo 
calling foo: In function foo
calling bar: In function bar
```

To clean up, all I have to do is type `make clean`:

```
$ make clean
make -C src clean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src'
make -C subdir2/. clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir2'
rm -rf ../../build/bar.o ../../include/bar.h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir2'
make -C subdir1/. clean
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir1'
rm -rf ../../build/foo.o ../../include/foo.h
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src/subdir1'
rm -rf ../build/main.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Development/make_example/src'
rm -rf package/demo
```

and all our build artifacts are gone:

```
$ ls -l */*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  165 Oct 23 12:54 src/main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  555 Oct 23 15:50 src/Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john  481 Oct 23 15:46 src/subdir.mk

src/subdir1:
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 89 Oct 23 12:29 foo.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 56 Oct 23 12:07 foo.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 32 Oct 23 15:16 Makefile

src/subdir2:
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 89 Oct 23 15:03 bar.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 56 Oct 23 14:49 bar.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 32 Oct 23 15:17 Makefile
```

Comment: I have been trying to use make ! I have one question though : Does make enable me not to use subdirs in import statements as well ?

Answer (score 2):

`gcc main.c dir/subdir/file.c -o main` is not the typical command form for most projects. It is used only for simple projects, such as student assignments.

Much commercial code consists of dozens, hundreds, or thousands of source files. It is not compiled all at once. Build tools such as `make` or Xcode are used to manage the project, and they will compile each source file separately to its own object file.

Object files may be grouped by subproject, may be collected into libraries, and may be further processed before being linked into an executable file or other product.

When the project is built, there is no need to compile all of the source files because they have been compiled previously. It is only necessary to compile source files for object files that may change due to source edits that have been made since the last time the project was built. Thus, the build tool may compile only a few of the hundreds of source files in the project, using an individual compile command for each. Having a single command that compiled all of the source files would be wasteful.

In some projects, there may be several variants of the source file for one header file. One header file may declare common interfaces, but several different source files may provide different implementations for those interfaces, to target different types of destination systems or to provide different characteristics, such as prioritizing speed over memory or vice-versa. In such a situation, knowing the header file does not identify which source file is to be compiled.

If you want your project to compile all source files that are implied by header files, you can write your own program that scans the `main.c` file to find included header files (possibly recursively) and generate commands to compile the associated source files.

Comment: There really should be an option for that though, I know it doesn't make sense for big projects but a lot of people aren't doing big projects at all